# Extract each word in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of addresses, and rows under that that are possible matches:

[image]

I'd like to be able to highlight (in green, say) the row that I think best matches the "Lookup Address" .

So for A1, since there's no state in the "Lookup Address", it's anybody's guess as to which is the "correct" one.  *However*, say that the lookup address is "123 Pennsylvania Ave, PA".  I'd like the "PA" result(s) below "Lookup Value" to be highlighted in Green.

As you can see, I have the state of each found address in column G.

I've been able to create a loop that goes through each found address range, but am having trouble thinking of how to do the state matching.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub check_Location_State_Pick_Most_Likely()
'After you run the XML reader and have your data, run this to highlight the most likely match
Dim lastRow As Integer, locStartRow As Integer, locEndRow As Integer
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
Dim locLookupState As String, locResultState As String

Dim stateArray() As Variant
stateArray = Array("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming")

Dim stateAbbreviationArray() As Variant
stateAbbreviationArray = Array("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY")

'If IsInArray("californa", stateArray) Then
'    Debug.Print "California is found in the array"
'Else
'    Debug.Print "Californa is not found in the arraay"
'End If

lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

' Since each location in column A start with "Lookup Address", we can use that
Dim nextString As String
nextString = "Lookup Address"

Dim noAddresses As Integer
noAddresses = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Columns(1), Columns(1)), "Lookup Address*")


For i = 1 To noAddresses
    If i = 1 Then
        locStartRow = 1
    Else
        locStartRow = Columns(1).Find(what:=nextString, after:=Cells(locStartRow, 1)).row
    End If

    locEndRow = Columns(1).Find(what:=nextString, after:=Cells(locStartRow, 1)).row
        If locEndRow = 1 Then locEndRow = Cells(60000, 1).End(xlUp).row  ' Because, after cell 71, there is no Lookup Address, so it loops back to top

    If locEndRow = lastRow Then
        Set rng = Range(Cells(locStartRow + 1, 1), Cells(locEndRow, 1))
    Else
        Set rng = Range(Cells(locStartRow + 1, 1), Cells(locEndRow - 1, 1))
    End If

    '  Do something with the ranges!
    Dim stateRange As Range
    Set stateRange = rng.Offset(0, 6)

    ' Now, loop through Cells(locStartRow,1) and try to see if this word exists in your StateArray.

Next i

End Sub
```

I'm thinking: For each cell with "Lookup Address", loop through each word and see if it exists in my state array.

I don't know how to loop through each word in a cell/string. I know how to do each character, but am hitting a wall on each word.  Would I want to somehow use `Mid()` to get each word?

Of course, if there's any other ideas on how to do this (end goal being an intelligent guess as to which of the address results matches the "lookup address").

I hope this makes sense, thanks for any ideas!

---

Thanks cyboashu! I was able to take your answer and work it into this, which is what I wanted :D

```
Dim arrComma
    arrComma = Split(Range(Cells(locStartRow, 1), Cells(locStartRow, 1)).Value2, " ")

    Dim lCtr As Long
    Dim arrSpace
    Dim lookupState As String
    For lCtr = LBound(arrComma) To UBound(arrComma)
        arrSpace = Split(arrComma(lCtr), Space(1))


        If Right(arrSpace(0), 1) = "," Then arrSpace(0) = Left(arrSpace(0), Len(arrSpace(0)) - 1)
        Debug.Print "Looking for the word: " & arrSpace(0)
        'If IsInArray(StrConv(CStr(arrSpace(0)), vbProperCase), stateArray) Then
        For Each xstate In stateArray
            If StrComp(CStr(xstate), arrSpace(0), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Debug.Print arrSpace(0) & " is found in the full State Name array"
                lookupState = arrSpace(0)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next xstate

    ' Since it didn't find any "Full Lenght" names, check the abbreviations
    If lookupState = "" Then
        Debug.Print arrSpace(0) & " was not found in full state name array, checking abbreviations..."
            For Each xstate In stateAbbreviationArray
            If StrComp(CStr(xstate), arrSpace(0), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Debug.Print arrSpace(0) & " is found in the Abbreviations array!"
                lookupState = stateArray(Application.Match(arrSpace(0), stateAbbreviationArray, False) - 1)
                Exit For
            End If

        Next xstate
        If lookupState = "" Then Debug.Print arrSpace(0) & " was not found in abbreviations array either."
    End If

    If lookupState <> "" Then Exit For

    Next lCtr

    Debug.Print "The state in the Lookup Address is: " & lookupState
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `split` function.
First split the address on "," separator.

```
Dim arrComma

arrComma=Split(range("A2").value2,",") 'Your cell address here
```

Then loop through all the elements of the array and split each array for space.

```
    Dim lCtr as Long
    Dim arrSpace
    For lCtr= lbound(arrComma) to ubound(arrComma) 
        arrSpace=Split(arrComma(lctr),space(1))
    Next
```

Then in the resulting array `arrSpace` loop through each word.

Comment: Thanks! I've almost got it with the above. Quick question- after I pull out each word and have it in `arrSpace(0)`, how do I check that value and see if it's in an array? I get `Compile Error: ByRef argument type mismatch` when trying to do (just after `arrSpace = Split(arrComma...`), `If IsInArray(arrSpace(0), stateArray) Then`..  I assume it's because `arrSpace(0)` isn't a string, and I need a string to compare?

Comment: Note on above comment - I was able to fix this by converting the `arrSpace(0)` to a string: `CStr(arrSpace(0))`.

Comment: Hmm - I'm getting an error when running it sometimes.  On In the `For lCtr` loop, I have (just after the `arrSpace = ` line) `Debug.print "Looking for " & arrSpace(0)`.  I get the error "Subscript out of Range".  This is because it's looking up a cell that has DOUBLE spaces in it ('this is single spaced but  this has two in front`).  How do I account for that?

Comment: Ah, I fixed that - just did Find/Replace on double spaces.  Also, FYI I just added this line after getting `arrSpace`: `If Right(arrSpace(0), 1) = "," Then arrSpace(0) = Left(arrSpace(0), Len(arrSpace(0)) - 1)`, effectively cutting out any trailing commas.